# Shared variable in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Basically, 'refresh' is a caching function, while 'printer' is intended to serve the result to output.
This example, obviously, fails at some point, unfortunately, python docs are no help with that.
Besides explanations, a working code would be highly appreciated.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from random import randrange
import time

manager = Manager()
x = manager.list()

def refresh():
    global x
    while True:
        y = []
        for i in range(5):
            y.append(randrange(100))
        x = y
        time.sleep(0.2)

def printer():
    while True:
        global x
        print(x)
        # Mind the different interval compared to 'refresh'
        time.sleep(0.3)

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Process(target=refresh)
    p.start()
    p1 = Process(target=printer)
    p1.start()
```

Comment: What fails? Were you getting some sort of error? Was something not working as expected? Why weren't the docs helpful?

Comment: Variable fails to be shared between two processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write `x = y`, you replaced a `manager.list()` object with a normal `list()` object, nothing will be shared.

if you want to continue using this paradigm, you could use a namespace object:

```
n = manager.Namespace()

def refresh():
    ...
    n.x = y

def printer():
    ...
    print(n.x)
```

ps: you need use `join` to wait for child process to finish, otherwise `Manager` will exit as main(parent) process exited:

```
p.join()
p1.join()
```

Comment: Have you tried running what you've just posted yourself?

Comment: of course, why you ask? https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9071311

Comment: Amazing now, failed for me for the first time cause I did not initialize n.x.

Answer (score 0):

In `refresh`, you're not modifying `x`, you're *replacing* it:

```
def refresh():
    global x
    while True:
        y = []
        for i in range(5):
            y.append(randrange(100))

        ## IN THIS LINE HERE
        ##
        ## When you set x = y, you're replaced your manager.list() with
        ## a normal, unshared list.
        x = y

        time.sleep(0.2)
```

You could replace it with:

```
x[:] = y
```

This will replace the *contents* of `x`.

Comment: Okay, what would be my strategy to assign 'y' contents to 'manager.x' or whatever this thing should be called in OOP-hell?